# BrainTree fake-nonce transaction succeed and fail randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

I'm using `BrainTree` ruby Gem, and in my tests, I perform transactions alternating between **fake-valid-mastercard-nonce** and **fake-valid-visa-nonce**, however in my test suit, it happens randomly that one of the transactions fails, I keep re running the tests until it all passes so that code is auto deployed (using some CI).

So is there any clue for this ? The requests logs are not very helpful:

```
POST /merchants/some_id/customers 201
POST /merchants/some_id/payment_methods 201
POST /merchants/some_id/transactions 422
```

Comment: Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/).

There's a variety of reasons as to why this may be occurring, including [duplicate transaction checking](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/transactions/duplicate-checking#configure-duplicate-transaction-checking), which you can manually configure. You can always grab the error response object, which will tell you if the transaction was gateway rejected - an indication of duplicate transaction checking.

Comment: thanks, this indeed may be the case, using same fake-nonce with same amount in short interval of time in different tests, will try now.